# Jquery selection - elements (detached, dimmed out in firebug)

Tags: jquery, firebug, knockout.js

I am trying to select some elements within a portion of the page

```
$table = $(".table");
console.log($table);//this is fine
$edit_butts = $(".btn_edit", $table);
console.log($edit_butts);//elements dimmed and seemingly detached from dom - no click binding etc work
```

Does anyone now why these elements are getting dettached?

In console

```
bright and when clicked element found in dom
    jQuery(table.table)

dimmed, when clicked firebug goes to edit screen
    jQuery(div.btn_edit, div.btn_edit, div.btn_edit, div.btn_edit, div.btn_edit, div.btn_edit, div.btn_edit, div.btn_edit)
```

Any help much appreciated.

Also I should point out but I'm not sure if relevant the portion of the page is wrapped with a knockoutjs with directive.

```
<table  class="table>
<!-- ko with: model.item -->
edit butts
<div class="btn_edit"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with` binding removes the children of the element that it is applied to and keeps a copy to use as a template.  If the item that the `with` is bound against changes, then the template is used to generate the content and this happens even for the initial rendering.

The `with` binding is actually the equivalent of `template: { if: myData, data: myData }`, which uses anonymous templates (the children of the element).

So, the elements are getting removed from the DOM.  I am not sure of your objective, but if you find the elements after `ko.applyBindings` is called, then you would have a reference to the current elements being used inside the `with` binding.